# How do i use flush function in Phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon

Like this. I want to flash message .

```
class TestController extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller{

public function indexAction()
{
  for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) 
  {
    echo $i . '<br>';
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    sleep(1);
  }       
}
}
```

This code don't work, Any  idea?

Comment: public/private functions need to be in classes.  For example, 

`class main{
public function indexAction()
{
  for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) 
  {
    echo $i . '<br>';
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    sleep(1);
  }       
}
}`

Answer (score 0):

Just print the output as usual:

```
class TestController extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller
{

public function indexAction()
{
  for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) 
  {
    echo $i . '<br>';        
  }       
}
```

In your view, place where the messages must be shown:

Volt:

```
{{ content() }}
```

Plain PHP:

```
<?php echo $this->getContent(); ?>
```